# How to concatenate string in YAML?

Tags: yaml, ansible

I am writing a playbook in which I need to execute mysql query and pass
output in json format. playbook code working fine just I want facing error in string `concatenate` part. If I am passing sample json string it is working fine.

```
- name: Execute php script with json parameter
  command:  php -f /path/to/php/test.php "{'colors':{'red','blue','yellow'}}"
  register: php_output
```

`output.stdout_lines` is variable already set in my playbook which contains output in `{'red','blue','yellow'}` format.

```
- name: Execute php script with json parameter
  command:  php -f /path/to/php/test.php '{"stdout_lines": {{output.stdout_lines}} }'
  register: php_output
```

So how can I concatenate `output.stdout_lines` variable in `'{"stdout_lines": {{output.stdout_lines}} }'` ? any suggestions

Comment: When you pass an array on an Ansible task, it will be executed once for each entry on the array. It will not concatenate the values during the execution as you are supposing. Take a look at http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_loops.html

Answer (score 3):

`stdout_lines` was created for convenience. Back in the day we only had `stdout`. Which is what you want, I think:

```
command:  php -f /path/to/php/test.php '{"stdout_lines": {{output.stdout}} }'
```

and if you want to really concat yourself, say because you have your own list of strings then you can use the Jinja2 built-in filter `join`:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tags: so9
  vars:
    - str_list: ['Hello', 'world', '!', ]
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="orig list={{ str_list }}"
    - debug: msg="concated = {{ str_list | join(' ') }}"
    - set_fact: concated_str="{{ str_list | join(' ') }}"
    - debug: msg="assigned to a variable concated_str = {{ concated_str }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this.

```
  vars:
- img_path: "/var/lib/libvirt/images/{{ instance_name }}-disk2.img"
```

Where instance name is a another variable

Answer (score 1):

This will do

```
  - name: Generate JSON output based on template
    template: src=colors.json.j2 dest=/tmp/colors.json
    with_items: colors
```

It will generate a file like

```
{'colors':
    {
        'blue',
        'red',
        'green',
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `to_json` filter is what you want.

Ansible doesn't store variables as JSON strings, it stores them as Python objects.  When you're debugging e.g. with `-vvv`, Ansible displays these Python objects as JSON strings, but that's for your convenience.

To produce the desired command:

```
- name: Execute php script with json parameter
  vars:
    # define my desired object
    my_object:
      colors: "{{ output.stdout_lines }}"
    # my_object contains a dict with a single key 
    #  "colors" who's value is the list contained 
    #  in output.stdoutlines
  command: "php -f /path/to/php/test.php {{ my_object | to_json | quote }}"
  register: php_output
```

`to_json` takes the object stored in `my_object` and outputs a JSON string.

`quote` automatically handles any shell quoting that might be required for the JSON string.  e.g. If my JSON string contains double-quotes, `quote` will wrap the whole JSON string in single-quotes.